# How to use scp on ssh for downloading file to local machine

Tags: ssh, scp

I had temporary access to server and I made command

```
scp user@example.com:/home/textfile.txt ./
```

Now it is just moved to the root of server. How to download it to local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find it in the directory where you ran the SCP command ...

Comment: Aham, Now I see it is in root of server... But how I will get it to local machine?

Comment: Using FTP or SFTP or SCP (Why didn't you transfer directly from the first server to your local machine? Accessright?)

Comment: There is no access to FTP,just ssh... I just got instructions like that ./, I am not experienced UNIX user. I just need file on local, but I lost two hours on most simple thing, what could be emailed to me, but sys administrators just like to complicate things. Noone give direct answer on simple question... How to get ths file to local?

Comment: Then you can SCP the file from your server to your local machine the same way you did the first time. On Window you can use [WINSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)